# Downloading the Azure Blob Container using R for specific dates

Tags: python, r, json, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to download all the folder JSONs and Subfolder JSONs for specific dates using R.

The folder structured that is followed is:
year/month/day/hour/min/xxxxxx.json

I have the SAS url for accessing the Azure BLOB container.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for the same. There is api_url from Azure Storage Services. We can hit the URL with prefix of the directory. The GET will return a XML. We can parse the XMl to get the list of the URLs. URLs are path to the .json file.

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/enumerating-blob-resources#ContainerList